# C# Microsoft Word automation Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

Situation: I have an open MS Word file and need to run my CLI application to find and replace some data in it.

Question: Is there any option to "freeze" changes preview. I want while find/replace is in process to "freezed" state and visualate preview after all replacement had been done.

I found answer, so question can be closed: I used `Application.ScreenUpdating` setting `false` and `true` respectively for `freesing` and `unfreezing`.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, so question can be closed: I used `Application.ScreenUpdating` setting `false and true` respectively for freesing and unfreezing.